# Equal spacing in bar graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this bar graph in MATLAB, created using the `bar` command:

[image]

I was wondering if there is any way to get rid of empty spaces
between 2478 and 2886, and between 4314 and 5130

If I can get the bars to have an equal amount of space in between them that would be perfect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As described in the documentation of [`bar`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html),

> `bar(x,y)` draws the bars at the locations specified by `x`.

which means that this behavior is intended: Each bar is drawn at the exact position specified by `x`.

To get equally spaced bars, you can use the [`categorical`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html) function, which converts `x` to a data type which is intended for discrete categories.
That way, you tell MATLAB that `x` is not a numerical vector where `x(i)` is the `x`-coordinate of the `i`-th element, but rather a simple label for that value.

```
bar(categorical(x), y)
```

[image: Bar graph with categorical x-values]

Comment: marvelous. Thank you sir

Answer (score 6):

Your bars are drawn in the locations of your x data, and are spaced accordingly.

You could plot against `[1, 2, 3, ..., 13]` and re-label the axes like so

Example data:

```
x = [1886,2070,2274,2478,2886,3090,3294,3498,3702,3960,4110,4314,5130];
y = rand(1,13)*5 + 32;
```

Plotting

```
bar( 1:numel(y), y );
set( gca, 'XTickLabel', x );
```

[image: plot]